Unable to remove audio noise using weak signal power calculated from FFT as threshold
Question
Please help understand the cause and solution of the problem of unable to remove the audio noise by using the signal power as filter threshold. If the approach is not correct, please advise the better or correct ways.
Background
Try to remove the audio noises in the JFK speech. For instance, ... my fellow Americans <noise> ask not what your country can do for you <noise> ..., which are the red rectangles in the waveform.

Ideally aiming to get similar to the melspectgram below where the noises are removed in between phrases.

Data
# https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/tests/jfk.flac
wget -P ./data https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/tests/jfk.flac

Idea
Using the power of the signal to remove noise as Professor Steve Brunton showed in Denoising Data with FFT. The code exceprt from CH02_SEC02_2_Denoise.ipynb in CODE.zip + DATA.zip (PYTHON CODE by Daniel Dylewsky, unzip into same folder):
fhat = np.fft.fft(f,n)                     # Compute the FFT
PSD = fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n             # Power spectrum (power per freq)

indices = PSD > 100       # Find all freqs with large power
fhat = indices * fhat     # Zero out small Fourier coeffs. in Y
ffilt = np.fft.ifft(fhat) # Inverse FFT for filtered time signal


Problem
Implemented the code, but it could not remove the noises in between phrases as the white cloudy parts seen in the mel spectgraum. Not sure why the weak power (white cloudy parts) cannot not been removed.

Code
First, find out the power range where the human voice 300 - 3000 Hz exists. From the power/frequency diagram, I should extract above -100 dB, hence this is the power threshold to filter.
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp


data, original_sampling_rate = librosa.load("./data/jfk.flac", sr=None)
sampling_rate = original_sampling_rate
N = num_total_samples = data.shape[0]


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Power per Frequency
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dft = np.fft.rfft(data, norm="forward")
amplitude = 2 * np.abs(dft)
db = 20 * np.log10(amplitude)
frequency = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=len(data), d=1/sampling_rate)

plt.figure().set_figwidth(8)
plt.plot(frequency, db)
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Power (dB)")
plt.grid(visible=True, which='major')
plt.grid(visible=True, which='minor', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5)
plt.xscale("log")

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Mel Spectrogram
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(
    y=data, sr=sampling_rate, n_mels=128, fmax=sampling_rate/2, n_fft=1024, hop_length=512
)
S_dB = librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=1, top_db=None, amin=1e-10)

plt.figure().set_figwidth(8)
librosa.display.specshow(S_dB, x_axis="time", y_axis="mel", sr=sampling_rate, fmax=sampling_rate/2)
plt.colorbar()


Extract the area surrounded by the threshold -100 dB and the 300-3000 band.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cut low/high frequencies with scipy.signal.butterworth
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HIGHCUT = 3000
LOWCUT = 300
ORDER = 10
bandpassed = butter_bandpass_filter(signal=data, lowcut=LOWCUT, highcut=HIGHCUT, sampling_rate=sampling_rate, order=ORDER)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cut low power < -100 dB
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
THRESHOLD = -100
fhat = np.fft.rfft(a=bandpassed, norm="forward", axis=-1)
fhat_amplitude = 2 * np.abs(fhat)
fhat_power = 20 * np.log10(fhat_amplitude)

# zero out < -100 dB
fhat_filter_indices = fhat_power > THRESHOLD
fhat_power_filtered = fhat * fhat_filter_indices

plt.figure().set_figwidth(8)
plt.plot(frequency, 20 * np.log10(2 * np.abs(fhat_power_filtered)))
plt.grid(visible=True, which='major')
plt.grid(visible=True, which='minor', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Power (dB)")
plt.grid()
plt.xscale("log")


However, the noises in-between were not removed.
data_filtered = np.fft.irfft(fhat_power_filtered, norm="forward")
plt.figure().set_figwidth(8)
plt.grid()
librosa.display.waveshow(y=data_filtered, sr=sampling_rate)

S_filtered = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=data_filtered, sr=sampling_rate, n_mels=128, fmax=sampling_rate/2)
S_filtered_dB = librosa.power_to_db(S_filtered)

plt.figure().set_figwidth(8)
librosa.display.specshow(S_filtered_dB, x_axis="time", y_axis="mel", sr=sampling_rate, fmax=sampling_rate/2)
plt.colorbar()



Workaround
If I cut the sound data with its amplitude, the result mel spectgram looks what needed.
data, original_sampling_rate = librosa.load("./data/jfk.flac", sr=None)
sampling_rate = original_sampling_rate

data = data * (data > 0.1)    # <--- Cut the small amplitude data

# Same code as above from here.


However, the sound has high note noise and the voice is like that of someone with stuffed nose. Also, if power is form amplitude as in power = (amplitude ** 2) / 2, then why cut by amplitude remove the noises in-between, but power cannot?
from IPython.display import (
    Audio, 
    display
)
display(Audio(data=data_filtered, rate=sampling_rate))


Butterworth filter
def butter_bandpass(
    lowcut,
    highcut,
    sampling_rate: int,
    order: int = 5
):
    """
    Args:
        signal: signal data to filter
        lowcut: low cut-off frequency
        highcut: high cut-off frequency
        sampling_rate: sampling rate used to sample the signal
        order: filter order
    Returns: filtered output
    """
    nyquist = 0.5 * sampling_rate
    low = lowcut / nyquist
    high = highcut / nyquist
    sos = sp.signal.butter(N=order, Wn=[low, high], btype='band', analog=False, output='sos')
    return sos


def butter_bandpass_filter(
    signal: np.ndarray,
    lowcut,
    highcut,
    sampling_rate: int,
    order: int = 5
):
    """Butterworth bandpath filter
    Args:
        signal: signal data to filter
        lowcut: low cut-off frequency
        highcut: high cut-off frequency
        sampling_rate: sampling rate used to sample the signal
        order: filter order
    """
    sos = butter_bandpass(
        lowcut=lowcut,
        highcut=highcut,
        sampling_rate=sampling_rate, order=order)
    y = sp.signal.sosfilt(sos=sos, x=signal)
    return y


Update
It looks zero-ing in the frequency domain is not a good idea according to Why is it a bad idea to filter by zeroing out FFT bins?, but I have no idea what the explanation mean.

Zeroing bins in the frequency domain is the same as multiplying by a rectangular window in the frequency domain. Multiplying by a window in the frequency domain is the same as circular convolution by the transform of that window in the time domain. The transform of a rectangular window is the Sinc function ($\sin(\omega t)/\omega t$).  Note that the Sinc function has lots of large ripples and ripples that extend the full width of time domain aperture.  If a time-domain filter that can output all those ripples (ringing) is a "bad idea", then so is zeroing bins.


I don’t have time to go through your lengthy question at the moment, but you might have better luck with a Weiner filter

The thresholding approaches are almost never the way to go. Consider the fact that you will get Gib's phenomena if you go with the "brickwall" frequency filtering approach. In addition, filtering the waveform will also remove the data that is not considered "noise" but still under the threshold that you pick. In this case, the waveform that is going from e.g., 1000 to -1000 will jump from +threshold to 0 and then from 0 to -threshold. There are many denoisers out there, check this one for example: https://pypi.org/project/noisereduce/

I still do not completely understand the exact mechanism, but using a threshold and zero-out in the frequency domain was a wrong way as explained in Why is it a bad idea to filter by zeroing out FFT bins?, which further broken down into the explanation in Explanation to layman on the effect of zero-ing in frequency domain

Zeroing out a bin is the same as subtracting out a perfect sine wave of a specific bin centered frequency.
Most (or all) real world signals are imperfect. If the signal you are trying to filter out is slightly different from an exactly perfect sinewave of that bin frequency, the subtraction will leave behind a lot of "junk".
Signals that are "between bins" are different from any (or any small subset of) basis vectors of an FFT, thus can't be removed by subtracting a basis vector, which are all perfect sine waves of bin centered frequencies, e.g. frequencies whose period is an exact integer sub-multiple of the FFT's length. The subtraction will leave behind, often nasty, "junk".


Weiner Filter
As suggested by Jdip, experimented it and got a better result with background noise reduced in the speech.
wienered = sp.signal.wiener(im=data, mysize=28) # <--- 28 is found out by tweakig mysize paramter.
bandpassed = butter_bandpass_filter(signal=wienered, lowcut=LOWCUT, highcut=HIGHCUT, sampling_rate=sampling_rate, order=ORDER)

S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=bandpassed, sr=sampling_rate, n_mels=128, fmax=sampling_rate/2)
S_dB = librosa.power_to_db(S)

plt.figure().set_figwidth(12)
librosa.display.specshow(S_dB, x_axis="time", y_axis="mel", sr=sampling_rate, fmax=sampling_rate/4)
plt.colorbar()



I recommend you check this: Gibbs phenomenon
